# Error after Enable Multi-Dex in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

While creating a Xamarin Android application, after adding the reference to Infragistics Chart control and the Google Play services, we had to enable the 'Enable Multi-Dex' property to `true` (Since the app hit the dex method limit of 65K).
We are getting an error

> ```
> ..\CREATEMULTIDEXMAINDEXCLASSLIST: Error: Expecting class path
> separator ';' before
> '\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\21.1.1\lib\shrinkedAndroid.jar' in
> argument number 8
> ```

I am using
Xamarin Studio Version 5.9 (build 431)
Xamarin.Android Version: 5.1.0

Please help to fix this Issue in Xamarin.

Comment: Have you already looked through the [docs](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)?

Comment: Got the same error... How did you fix that ?

Comment: I kept reading the recommendation to install the Android SDK at a nondefault directory without spaces (e.g., C:\Android), because the default directory is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android which contains 2 spaces that mess with some command lines' demarcation of where command-line arguments end.  I had no trouble with the default directory until I turned on Multi-Dex support.

Answer (score 10):

We had the same problem on our build server, and we've had to move the Android SDK to a path with no spaces e.g. `C:\android-sdk\...`

Obviously we needed to update the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable to the new path, and set the SDK paths in Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio.

This has solved the problem for us.

Answer (score 3):

For those who don´t want to change the Android SDK actual location plus ANDROID_HOME env variable, a simple link is enough:

```
mklink /D "C:\android-sdk" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk"
```

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, there is also a bug if you have JDK 1.8 installed..

See this thread
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44013

Unfortunately the actual bug is inaccessible to general public..
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=42669

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing this problem any time I make an update that change or install a new build-tools folder. So I decided to store the solution here for myself and for whom could benefit from this solution.

Some of the bugzilla link in other solutions or comments are not accessible from anyone.
The reason for this is an issue with the Android SDK on Windows machines.
The following fix needs to be applied to the build server and developer machines:

1. The fix is to adjust the **mainDexClasses.bat** in the Android SDK. Search for this file and apply the fix to all instances. The first thing is locate the folder **android-sdk** and sub **build-tools**. My path is for example
   C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\
   check inside the folders named with the version number like xx.x.x (e.g. 24.0.1)
2. So inside the **mainDexClasses.bat** file locate the following block of text:

if DEFINED output goto redirect
call "%java_exe%" -Djava.ext.dirs="%frameworkdir%" com.android.multidex.MainDexListBuilder "%disableKeepAnnotated%" "%tmpJar%" "%params%"
goto afterClassReferenceListBuilder
:redirect
call "%java_exe%" -Djava.ext.dirs="%frameworkdir%" com.android.multidex.MainDexListBuilder "%disableKeepAnnotated%" "%tmpJar%" "%params%" 1>"%output%"
:afterClassReferenceListBuilder

**And replace with:**

SET params=%params:'=%
if DEFINED output goto redirect
call "%java_exe%" -Djava.ext.dirs="%frameworkdir%" com.android.multidex.MainDexListBuilder %disableKeepAnnotated% "%tmpJar%" %params%
goto afterClassReferenceListBuilder
:redirect
call "%java_exe%" -Djava.ext.dirs="%frameworkdir%" com.android.multidex.MainDexListBuilder %disableKeepAnnotated% "%tmpJar%" %params% 1>"%output%"
:afterClassReferenceListBuilder

3. Clean and build again.

Comment: This is not soving my issue .. Did it helped you ?

Answer (score -2):

Please Put your SDK into where is available Enough space and then put your jar or dll file there it will worked.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem. To resolve it you must go to the properties of your project and in the option `Android Options` in packaging you disable `Multi-Dex`. And in the debugger option choose `Xamarin` or not `Microsoft`.
I think that it resolves your problem.