# How can I change where the Android SDK manager installs things?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-sdk-manager

I'm on a very small 128 gig SSD and need to install various android SDKs to my hard drive on this machine (d:), I'm wondering if there is a way to actually change where the Android SDK manager installs packages, and I'm also wondering if I did happen to change the install directory, what would I need to move around to ensure nothing breaks with Xamarin? Like for example would I have to move my previously installed Android SDKs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Android SDK Manager install packages to where the `android-sdk` folder is located. You can find out where your Android SDK is located by different means, including:

1. From the **Android SDK Manager**

   1. Open `Tools -> Android -> Android SDK Manager`
   2. The path will be displayed at the top of the view in the `SDK Path`
2. From **Visual Studio**

   1. Navigate to `Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Settings`
   2. The path is displayed at the [`Android SDK Location` entry](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/#Configure_the_Installation)
3. From **Xamarin Studio**

   1. Navigate to `Tools -> Options -> Projects -> SDK Locations -> Android`
   2. The path is displayed at the `Android SDK` entry

As for instance, if you were to install a new SDK (say 24), that would be copied to `.../android-sdk/platforms/android-24/`.

What you could do is to simply move the `android-sdk` to any other folder of your liking. I have done this myself due to an [issue with MultiDexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776964/error-after-enable-multi-dex-in-xamarin-android), where I moved the SDK to `C:/android-sdk/`. Just remember to update the path as described in the list above.